# Get parts of string then update it

Tags: bash

I have this string

```
blah --arg1 --arg2 --etc doh
```

sometimes `doh` ending in slash, sometimes not.

i need to extract `doh` and assign to a var.

then replace it with `/some/path/doh`

I wont put here my tries, they are way too ugly.

--- updated ---

mm, not sure i understand the answers, sorry.

the final string should be like:

```
blah --arg1 --arg2 --etc /some/path/doh
```

and `doh` assigned to a var, say `foo`

Comment: Derp. I misread the question. In case you like: **[http://ideone.com/GB3Hd](http://ideone.com/GB3Hd)** for a C# solution ... <grin/>

Comment: By the way (to the other commenters): general hint, you can **upvote** comments (no need to duplicate obvious corrections :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kinda ugly but working

first of all getting rid of eventual trailing slashes:

```
$ str='blah --arg1 --arg2 --etc doh///'
$ str=$(shopt -s extglob; echo "${str%%+(/)}")
$ echo $str
blah --arg1 --arg2 --etc doh
```

next extracting `doh`

```
$ var=${str##* }
$ echo $var
doh
```

and lastly removing it from string and adding back prefixed by `/some/path`

```
$ echo "${str%"$var"} /some/path/$var"
blah --arg1 --arg2 --etc  /some/path/doh
```

Comment: mm, that's it! works exactly. though quite long... will try to optimize it. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use something like [`getopts`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) to parse the options, it's just

```
echo "/some/path/$1"
```

Comment: will this extract `doh` without trailing slashes? how to add first part of string before `/some/path`?

Comment: No, use `"${1%/}"` to remove a trailing slash. (No harm if there is no slash.)

Answer (score 0):

If the string is not command line arguments:

```
VAR="blah --arg1 --arg2 --etc doh"
LAST=`echo $VAR | awk -F" " '{ print $NF }'`
echo "/some/path/$LAST"
```

Comment: No need `EXPORT`, nor `-F ` for `awk`

Comment: You can `echo "${$#}"` natively in Bash. Remember the double quotes. It is not clear from the question whether the OP wants the first non-option argument, the last argument, or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If it really arguments from script, see what's tripleee wrote.

If not:

```
echo "/some/path/$(echo "$STRING" | awk '{print $NF}')"
```